Kafka metrics for Spring-Kafka consumers - possibility to decrease number of threads 'micrometer-kafka-metrics'
I have Spring-Boot application with multiple consumers with the same consumer group using @KafkaListener from Spring-Kafka. After investigation, I discovered that per each consumer it creates 4 threads:

kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread - created from AbstractCoordinator
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer* / kafka-listener-* - created from KafkaMessageListenerContainer,  thread name pattern is based on id field by @KafkaListener if provided
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - created from KafkaMessageListenerContainer (instead it's possible to set custom thread pool via new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>().getContainerProperties().setScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
micrometer-kafka-metrics - created from KafkaMetrics

The current question is only about threads micrometer-kafka-metrics, the rest are descoped.
micrometer-kafka-metrics is a daemon thread created by io.micrometer:micrometer.core inside KafkaMetrics:
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
    .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new NamedThreadFactory("micrometer-kafka-metrics"));

The chain of invocations is the following. KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration (from spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure) creates a single instance of MicrometerConsumerListener (from spring-kafka) per application, and after that MicrometerConsumerListener has method consumerAdded(..) that is invoked per each Consumer. It creates KafkaClientMetrics (that extended from KafkaMetrics).
As a result, the number of consumers is the same as the number of threads micrometer-kafka-metrics.
If we have consumer factory concurrency as N (new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>().setConcurrency(N);) and number of @KafkaListener as M (one per each topic, as we have M topics), as a result we have N * M threads with name micrometer-kafka-metrics.
In most cases N * M is not a big number, but in some rare cases it might be a few hundred (like in my case). I want to leave number of concurrent consumers as is, but decrease number of metrics threads, cause metrics threads are quite lightweight and scheduled with a fixed rate (1 minute by default).
So I'm looking at ways how to decrease the number of these threads. Ideally would be great to have the ability to pass there optional custom thread pool, that will be shareable for all consumers and with the desired number of threads. Looks like currently it's not possible and micrometer does not provide such capability (maybe in that case makes sense to contribute), or am I missing something? Are there other options?

Apparently this is something what has to be fixed in that KafkaMetrics to let us to inject our own ScheduledExecutorService. I suggest to open a GH issue for Micrometer project: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues

thank you, will open issue to micrometer-metrics. posted question here initially just  to clarify that there are no other workarounds

Well, there is one: implement your own MicrometerConsumerListener. And you can borrow the logic from that KafkaClientMetrics and its super KafkaMetrics.

issue and contribution proposal have been submitted to micrometer repo
